# How to retrieve addresses using the odata endpoint

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, dynamics-crm-365

I'm trying to retrieve an address on a standard entity.

the request is the following :

```
https://mycrm.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts(guid)
```

In this example, I get all fields, but the ones that is of interest to me is `address1_addressid`, which seems to be a Guid, referencing some of record, but I cannot find it in the "Many to One" relationship list I retrieved using the following command :

```
https://mycrm.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='contact')?$select=LogicalName&$expand=ManyToOneRelationships($select=ReferencingAttribute,ReferencedEntity)
```

I would like to retrieve those addresses in a generic manner, as I'm working on a generic NetStandard 2.0 library. I won't be able to know on which entity I'll be working, and thus won't be able to hard-code a list of addresses field names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to find the Contact to Address relationship:

`https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='customeraddress')?$select=LogicalName&$expand=ManyToOneRelationships($select=ReferencingAttribute,ReferencedEntity)`

[image: AddressRelationship]

I got an error with `https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts(guid)?$expand=address1_addressid`.

I looked into the MetaData and discovered that `address1_addressid` has a type of Primary Key:
[image: PrimaryKey]

While a normal lookup field has a type of Lookup:
[image: Lookup]

Considering the error message that appears when attempting to expand `address1_addressid`, I think the issue is `address1_addressid`'s data type.

> Property 'address1_addressid' on type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.contact'
>   is not a navigation property or complex property. Only navigation
>   properties can be expanded.

It would seem that rather than using `$expand` to get the address details, you'd have to make a separate call for it:
`https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/customeraddresses(guid)`

**UPDATE**
By reviewing the full Contact-Address relationship, via this query: `https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='customeraddress')?$select=LogicalName&$expand=ManyToOneRelationships`.

I discovered the `ReferencedEntityNavigationPropertyName` was set to `Contact_CustomerAddress`.

[image: fullRelationship]

The error message before talked about the Navigation property so I gave it a shot. Using that property named allowed me to expand the Address info from the Contact:

`https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts(guid)?$expand=Contact_CustomerAddress`

Interestingly, expanding that navigation property returns all 3 customer addresses:
[image: Addresses]

Comment: Thank (again ;) ) Aron, will try this as soon as I've time.

Comment: You're welcome @Dremor. I found out more and updated the answer.